# How to define events to use in Bayes' rule?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

"In transmitting dot and dash signals, a communication system changes 1/4 of the dots to dashes and 1/3 of the dashes to dots. If 40% of the signals transmitted are dots and 60% are dashes, what is the probability that a dot received was actually a transmitted dot?"

Answer = 3/5

Hello, everyone,

I am having issues wording the events such that they fit coherently in Bayes' rule even though I am able to solve the problem mathematically. 
Could someone please give me an example of their wordings for the events?

Comment: I think this link should help. It has the exact same question and an answer with proper working out. The answer there matches to your answer, 3/5. https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/fundamentals-of-probability-with-stochastic-processes-3rd-edition-chapter-3.4-solutions-9780131453401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$A = \text{"A randomly selected transmitted signal is a dot"}$$
$$B = \text{"A randomly selected received signal is a dot"}$$

Then you have:
$$p(\bar B|A) = 1/4$$
$$p(B|\bar A) = 1/3$$
$$p(A) = 0.4$$
$$p(\bar A) = 0.6$$

Now just apply Bayes' theorem to find $p(A|B)$.